# ServiceLoader where type parm is itself generic

Tags: java, generics, serviceloader

```
class ServiceLoader<S> implements Iterable<S> {
    // ...
}

interface Foo<T> {
    // ...
}

class FooRepository {
    void add(Iterable<Foo<?>> foos) {
        // ...
    }
}

FooRepository repo = new FooRepository();
repo.add(ServiceLoader.load(Foo.class));
```

This yields a compiler error: "The method `add(Iterable<Foo<?>>)` in the type FooRepository is not applicable for the arguments `(ServiceLoader<Foo>)`".

I was hoping to be able to treat an `Iterable<Foo>` as an `Iterable<Foo<?>>`, but on its own it doesn't seem to work. What would be the cleanest way to transmute the result of `ServiceLoader.load(Foo.class)` into something I can feed to `FooRepository.add()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about [`java.util.ServiceLoader<S>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), then its Javadoc says:

> The *provider class* is typically not the entire provider itself but rather a proxy which contains enough information to decide whether the provider is able to satisfy a particular request together with code that can create the actual provider on demand. [...] The only requirement enforced by this facility is that provider classes must have a zero-argument constructor so that they can be instantiated during loading.

Combined with the way that the provider class is clearly instantiated using reflection, that tells me that a provider class declared with a generic type argument will in fact be instantiated as a **raw type**.

Thus, because you're passing in an object of type `Class<Foo>` -- and there's no way in Java to construct a object of type `Class<Foo<Bar>>` -- then what you get back is what you asked for, an `Iterable<Foo>`, where `Foo` is the raw type created from `Foo<T>`.

Unfortunately, I think the simple answer is: Don't do that then! Either make your provider class be a concrete subclass of the generic type, or else make your provider class be simply a factory that can construct new objects of the appropriate generic type.

Honestly, I can't think of any good reason to make a generic service provider class anyway -- where would you provide the type arguments?  I think the factory mechanism is your best bet.

Comment: Yep. Ultimately, one cannot treat a Foo-of-Bar as a Foo-of-Bar-of-?. I worked around it by hiding the call to ServiceLoader.load() behind something that can present the ServiceLoader's findings as an Iterable-of-the-type-I-wanted.

Answer (score 0):

That's because generic types are for compile time only. They are erased at runtime (type erasure). The generic type T of the Foo interface will no longer be known at runtime, so the "add" method of the Repo class will not let you further (generically) type the argument type (will not let you have the argument of type `Foo<?>`, since it can't guarantee that inside the method you'll be able to actually treat that argument as an argument of type `F<?>`. It only knows that it's of type Foo, because that's an actual type, but it won't let you generically type it further. Your code will run if you  change the method to

`void add(Iterable<Foo> foos)`

Comment: True. Was hoping to minimize warnings about the usage of a raw type.

Answer (score -2):

The blame falls on Java's type system. You need brute cast.

Either cast `Foo.class` to `Class<Foo<?>>`, or `ServiceLoader<Foo>` to `ServiceLoader<Foo<?>>`. Both are obviously harmless.

Comment: Such casts fail at compile time.

Comment: you can cast any type to any type